# How to change the color of trendline using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made a plot using geom_jitter and geom_smooth, and I've specified the color of the points by group but I haven't been able to specify the color of the trendlines. Right now they're all the same, and I want to be able to change them so that they're not the same color.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Max, y=count, group=Patch_type,fill=factor(Patch_type)))+
  geom_jitter(color='black', shape=21, size=4)+
  labs(title = "Abundance of moths by maximum temperature", x="Temperature", y="Abundance")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#EDF8B1", "#7FCDBB", "#2D7FB8"), name="Patch Type")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14))+
  geom_smooth(method="glm")
```

I've tried moving my scale_fill_manual argument to the end that that it applies to both the geom_jitter and geom_smooth arguments, but that didn't work. I tried using 'color=' in the ggplot argument, but then I wasn't able to specify the color of the points and the trendlines.

Comment: Try `geom_smooth(aes(color = factor(Patch_type)), method="glm")`. A line has only a `color`. Hence you have to map on the `color` aes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.